# Table valued function when converted to stored procedure runs slow

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I've a pretty complex table valued function doing inner joins over various tables. I've to tune this function. SQL wan't showing actual execution plan executed inside the function. So I thought to convert this to stored procedure and see the query plan. When I ran the original function as well as this new stored procedure in single batch, 100% time was consumed by stored procedure.

Is this expected? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: It really depends if SQL is able to cache the plan effectively or not, was this run from cold?

Comment: yeah. I just created the proc and in next I executed both folks together. How to make SQL cache plan?

Comment: (If you ran the SP first, could it be that the table-valued function was able to just re-use a cached result from the SP and therefore took 0%?)

Comment: Caching will occur naturally on the server dependent upon a few things such as parameters passed to the sproc.  Run the same sproc a few times with the same arguments - it will likely have been cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. A multi-statement table valued function (TVF) is a black box and the internal processing isn't visible.

It isn't running *slow* (well it could be for other reasons, but this isn't the question). The optimiser can not judge the TVF vs the procedure correctly and so allocates 100% of the batch to the proc.

One way is to run the code (separatley) and use SQL Profiler to note Duration, Reads, CPU.

Comment: I later created another SP (call this SP2 and 1st one SP1) over this TVF, and then ran both in batch. SP2 was still faster by a factor of 100%. Why is it so?

Comment: Because the TVF is still a black box, whether it is wrapped in an SP or not